# Complex representation and Dual representation notation

Tags: notation, representation-theory

Let's say we have a representation $\rho$ of $G$ on a vector space $V$. Wikipedia refers to the [dual representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_representation) as $V^*$, but the [dual vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_vector_space) as $\overline{V}$. It does the opposite for the [conjugate representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_representation) and the [conjugate vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_vector_space). What is normal accepted notation for these, and is the discrepancy just an error by someone who edited Wikipedia?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard notation for the dual vector space to a vector space $V$ is $V^*$.  If $V$ is a $G$-module for some group $G$ (equivalently, one has a representation $\rho \colon G \to \operatorname{End} V$), then one often also writes $V^*$ for the dual module.  The notion of a conjugate vector space (and representation) is less common.